# Patent status information

Tags: ownership, patent-lifetime

In reference to the patent: [US3731965](https://www.google.com/patents/US3731965)

Is this patent current or expired? If expired is it public domain or can I patent it? If it is current where can I find this item for purchase?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about the production of products covered by these patents is outside the scope of this site.